# How much static HTML should I serve with React?

Tags: reactjs

**How much static HTML should I serve with React as opposed to just leaving it in the HTML file?**

(I am just getting started with React.)

I have a single page application, which, greatly simplified, looks like this:

```
<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="header">
      <div id="header_dynamic_content">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dynamic_content">
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Is it best/common practice to use React to only handle the dynamic content and to leave everything that is static in the HTML file? Or should I use React Components to serve everything?

So this?

```
class DynamicOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      /* My Content */
    );
  }
}

class DynamicTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      /* My Content */
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DynamicOne />, document.getElementById('header_dynamic_content'));
ReactDOM.render(<DynamicTwo />, document.getElementById('dynamic_content'));
```

or this?

```
class DynamicOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      /* My Content */
    );
  }
}

class DynamicTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      /* My Content */
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="header">
          <div id="header_dynamic_content">
            <DynamicOne />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="dynamic_content">
          <DynamicTwo />
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Your second version, rendering a single `<App />`, is generally the standard. But components have to return a single element, so you need to wrap the return in a single `<div>` or a `React.Fragment`, which is abbreviated as `<> </>`.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the correction also and I have edited my question to reflect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to React Documentation:

> Applications built with just React usually have a single root DOM node. If you are integrating React into an existing app, you may have as many isolated root DOM nodes as you like.

[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom)

Happy coding :)