# Should I render all my HTML with React JSX or keep the static HTML in my .html file, and why?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering, react-dom

For a page that has mostly static HTML and a few dynamically rendered elements, is it best practice to render **all** HTML through React, or to leave the static HTML in an HTML file and only render targeted elements as needed with React?

---

*Here's what I'm considering for the **why**, feedback welcome:*

- **All HTML in React**: because this ensures all HTML is coming from one centralized location and is easier to understand
- **Only dynamic HTML in React, because**:

  1. A plain html file is most likely to render the DOM successfully, so even if the React app scripts have an issue you'll still render the rest of the page
  2. From an efficiency perspective, is an HTML file faster to load than React rendering?

---

I know this is similar to this question, but the one answer didn't really address the "why". [How much static HTML should I serve with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075299/how-much-static-html-should-i-serve-with-react)

Comment: There's not going to be a "why" because there's no correct answer here. HTML is strings so it sucks that's why. React is JavaScript so you get type-time feedback with eslint and proper error messages from the react error handlers

Comment: Those are good reasons I didn't consider for why React is better. Sounds like you're in the 'React for rendering everything' camp?

Comment: Yes. I haven't written raw html in years

Comment: Thanks. I now realize Stack Overflow doesn't allow opinion questions (since this one got closed), but I feel like opinion is unavoidable when asking an 'industry best practices' question. It still adds value, especially for beginner devs that are not sure how most devs do certain tasks.

Comment: There are better places to ask that kind of thing like reddit